# How to sketch the region determined by the limits of integration?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I have seen many videos and tutorials on how to sketch a region determined by double integrals however I am not sure on how to do this one because the example is slightly different from the videos I have seen. When I tried sketching this I got a semi-circle with the base on the y-axis, but I am not sure if it is correct. How do I sketch this one?

$$\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}3dxdy$$

Comment: The inner integral is in $dx$, the outer in $dy$. Consider $y$ fixed. Then the integration varies depending on that. The domain is not always easy to see, but in this case you're right: it's a semicircle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, draw the lines $y=\pm1$ from the outer integral. Then the inner integral vary from $x=0$ to $x = \sqrt{1-y^2}$, which is a semicircunference with diameter in $y$-axis for $x\geq0$.
This integral could be also written as $\int_{-1}^{1} 3\sqrt{1-y^2}dy$

[image]

Comment: hi how do you know that the most outer part of the semi circle is at x = 1?

Comment: because $x = \sqrt{1-y^2}$ is the equation of a semicircunference with radius 1. (It comes from $x^2 + y^2 = 1$).